# Weakly convergent sequence of operators on Hilbert space is norm-bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, weak-convergence, von-neumann-algebras

Nomenclature in this area of mathematics is so confusing, I cannot even determine what I am to prove here. (Weak convergence can mean about three things, and so can boundedness.) Is it

$$f_n \xrightarrow{WOT}f \Rightarrow (\exists M ∈ ℝ_{≥ 0})(\forall n ∈ ℕ)(\lVert f_n \rVert ≤ M)?
$$

In all three books I use (Rynne & Youngson, Conway, and Murphy), 'norm-bounded' is nowhere defined. I guess for analysts this may be obvious from the context, but for me it isn't.

Comment: Btw, I use for WOT-convergence the definition that for all $h, k ∈ H$: $\langle f_nh, k\rangle → \langle fh, k\rangle$.

Comment: *Bounded* is a notion that is defined for metric spaces. Rynne & Youngson define bounded in the context of a metric space in Definition 1.24. The fact that a norm induces a metric is mentioned in the preface, and done explicitly before Example 2.10. Conway defines it on Definiton IV.2.5. In both books "bounded set" appear in the index. I don't see a definition in Murphy, though like I said such definition belongs to metric spaces and not functional analysis.

Comment: Sooo, a (norm-)bounded *sequence* is meaningless? Or should we interpret the sequence $(f_n)_n$ as the set $\{\lVert f_n \rVert \mid n ∈ ℕ \}$, and use the boundedness-meaning of sets you mention?

Comment: "Norm" is there to tell you which metric to use. And a sequence is a function, so "bounded" means that its image is bounded. In this case the image of the function is the set $\{f_n:\ n\}$, and this set is bounded in the metric induced by the norm precisely if the number set $\{\|f_n\|:\ n\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that’s useful! Thanks! I’m now trying to prove precisely that, in a new topic with the same name. (Invoking UBP, that is.)

Comment: I closed the new question as a duplicate because it is already answered on the site (by me, in particular, so it would have been not too nice from me to repeat my old answer).

Comment: Absolutely, great trick, using it twice! Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) $ $

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer. (I've since been told that my definition of norm-boundedness was the right one.)

We have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n → \infty} \lVert f_n \rVert &= \lim_{n → \infty} \sup\{\lVert f_n(h) \rVert\mid \lVert h \rVert≤ 1\} =  \lim_{n → \infty} \sup\{\sqrt{\langle f_n(h), f_n(h) \rangle} \mid \lVert h\rVert ≤ 1 \} \\
&= \sup\{\sqrt{\langle f(h), f(h) \rangle} \mid \lVert h\rVert ≤ 1 \} \\
&= \sup\{\lVert f(h) \rVert \mid \lVert h\rVert ≤ 1 \} = \lVert f \rVert.
\end{align*}

Now I would guess this implies boundedness of the sequence (if there are $n ∈ ℕ$ with $\lVert f_n \rVert > \lVert f \rVert$ it can only be finitely many, say, some finite $S \subset ℕ$, say, and we can take $M := \max(\{\lVert f \rVert\}∪\{\lVert f_n\rVert\ \mid n ∈ S\})+1$, for instance.

Problem is that I rarely seem to know which steps are allowed, why they are allowed, and which verifications actually need to be done.. The argument I presented above *seems* convincing, but please feel free to correct/add anything I may have missed.

Comment: The conclusion is wrong. Weak convergence implies that the norms $\|f_n\|$ are bounded by a constant, but it does not mean that $\|f_n\|\to \|f\|.$

Comment: Ah, there we go. Which step(s) is(are) unwarranted?

Comment: The penultimate equality is wrong.

Comment: Besides the concrete mistake that was mentioned above, you never used that you had a sequence, and the result is not true for nets. Also, it doesn't make sense to write $\lim_n\|f_n\|$ when you don't know that such limit exists (and it won't exist in most cases, even if the sequence of norms is bounded).